# how to connect achartEngine to database?

Tags: achartengine

I am using achartEngine to draw graphics in my android application. i am setting data in the code. Now I need to get data from mySQL database and display it in my graphics. I am using PHP web service and JSOn parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can write some bridge code that will get data from your database and populate the AChartEngine datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I can get data and display it in list view using this code : { `

public class Linedbconn extends Activity {

```
String id,abscisses,ordonnees;
```

// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

```
// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_line_graph = "http://api.androidhive.info/application_connect/line_graph.php";




// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_LINE = "line";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_ABSCISSES = "abscisses";
private static final String TAG_ORDONNEES = "ordonnees";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_linedbconn);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // getting product id (id) from intent
    id = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
    abscisses=intent.getStringExtra(TAG_ABSCISSES);
    ordonnees=intent.getStringExtra(TAG_ORDONNEES);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetLineDetails().execute();

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete line details
 * */
class GetLineDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Linedbconn.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading information. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting information in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                    // getting line details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that line details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_line_graph, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Line Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received line details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_LINE); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // line with this id found
                        // Edit Text
                        //txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        //txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        //txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        //txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        //txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        //txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        abscisses=(String)product.getString(TAG_ABSCISSES);
                        ordonnees=(String)product.getString(TAG_ORDONNEES);

                    }else{
                        // product with id not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

But when i want to put these values in a table of string to use them in my chart it does not work
`

Answer (score 0):

Well what I have done is;

```
// to display the values for a single category (ie. sales per month)
//put the data into an array
int[] y = new int[12];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    y[i] = Integer.valueOf(sales);
}
//Create the Category series (ie. one value (sales) per month)          
CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("");
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  series.add( y[i]);
}
```

Now instance the dataset

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
```

Create the type of graph you want with a render

```
// This is how the "Graph" itself will look like
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Sales per month");
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{30, 30, 20, 20});
        mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
etc....
```

and finally make and show the graph

```
//make
mChartView1 = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, dataset,mRenderer, null);

//show
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)step.findViewById(R.id.barChart);
layout.addView(mChartView1);
```

if you want to make multiple categories (ie sales per month for certain years, do this;

```
// to display the values for a several categories (ie. sales per month per year)
//put the data into an array

int[] y = new int[12];

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
for (int year = 0; year < numberofYears; year++){
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("");
   //get the data for the specific year then 
   //iterate through it values and add the data to the series
   double[] v = values.get(year);
   for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
      series.add(v[i]);
   }
   dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
}
```

Hope this helps!